# How can I create a List of lists for each root node childs?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Dialog_System
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<List<TreeNode>> allnodes = new List<List<TreeNode>>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for(int i = 0; i < advancedTreeView1.Nodes.Count; i++)
            {
                PrintNodesRecursive(advancedTreeView1.Nodes[i]);
            }
        }

        public List<TreeNode> PrintNodesRecursive(TreeNode oParentNode)
        {
            allnodes.Add(oParentNode);

            // Start recursion on all subnodes.
            foreach (TreeNode oSubNode in oParentNode.Nodes)
            {
                PrintNodesRecursive(oSubNode);
            }

            return allnodes;
        }
    }
}
```

If the List allnodes was like this :

```
List<TreeNode> allnodes = new List<TreeNode>();
```

The result was :

[image: Nodes]

But I want that root node 0 will be a List of it's own with his childs.
Then root node 1 to be a List of it's own childs nodes too.
And so on. So in the List allnodes I will Lists for each root node and his childs.

For example under root Node0 should be listen the nodes 3,4,5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `List<List<TreeNode>>` doen't work for this, as the number of levels is given in advance and is always 2. You must create a class that can accept a value and a list of children

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public List<Node<T>> Children { get; } = new List<Node<T>>();
}
```

This defines a recursive structure, since each `Node<T>` contains a `List<Node<T>>`. It could have a fixed value type of `TreeNode`; however, by making it generic, we make it reusable for other cases.

Basically, you want to clone the structure of the `TreeView`. We can clone like this:

```
public Node<TreeNode> CloneRecursive(TreeNode treeNode)
{
    var node = new Node<TreeNode> { Value = treeNode };
    foreach (TreeNode subTreeNode in treeNode.Nodes) {
        node.Children.Add(CloneRecursive(subTreeNode));
    }
    return node;
}
```

A problem we face, is that we don't have a root node in the `TreeView`, as the `TreeView` itself is not a node. Therefore I am using the trick of creating a dummy `TreeNode` representing the whole `TreeView`.

```
var rootNode = new TreeNode("root", advancedTreeView1.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().ToArray());
Node<TreeNode> clone = CloneRecursive(rootNode);
List<Node<TreeNode>> allnodes = clone.Children;
```

Alternatively, we can adapt your solution with the loop:

```
List<Node<TreeNode>> allnodes = new List<Node<TreeNode>>();
foreach (TreeNode treeNode in advancedTreeView1.Nodes) {
    allnodes.Add(CloneRecursive(treeNode));
}
```

---

Another possibility is to store only the node texts (it's possible because our node class is generic).

```
public Node<string> CloneTextRecursive(TreeNode treeNode)
{
    var node = new Node<string> { Value = treeNode.Text };
    foreach (TreeNode subTreeNode in treeNode.Nodes) {
        node.Children.Add(CloneTextRecursive(subTreeNode));
    }
    return node;
}
```

Comment: Getting error in the foreach on this line : allnodes.Add(CloneRecursive(treeNode)); cannot convert from 'Form1.Node<System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode>' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode'

Comment: Because `allNodes` must be typed as `List<Node<TreeNode>>` (not just `List<TreeNode>`). Alternatively, you can make `Node` non-generic. Then this becomes `List<Node>`.